# Is there a way to count months between two columns extracted dates?

Tags: mysql

I have this small sample from a database:

| id_doc | fecIn | fecAlt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04564494 | 2019-12-22 | 2020-01-22 |
| 04564498 | 2019-12-22 | 2020-02-06 |
| 04512870 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-05 |
| 04566760 | 2020-01-07 | 2020-02-12 |
| 04500207 | 2020-02-29 | 2020-03-20 |
| 04502614 | 2020-03-19 | 2020-05-27 |
| 04503127 | 2020-03-31 | 2020-06-02 |

I want to count months between 'fecIn' and 'fecAlt',
without taking into account the days in the dates.

So i Try:

```
SELECT 
d.id_doc,
d.fecIn,
d.fecAlt,
DATE_FORMAT(d.fecIn,'%Y-%m') as MonthIn,
DATE_FORMAT(d.fecAlt,'%Y-%m') as MonthAlt
FROM test.docs d
```

So far I get only year and month. I stuck here . Is there a way to count months from the way I get 'MonthIn' and 'MonthAlt'?
The Result I want is the last column:

| id_doc | fecIn | fecAlt | MontIn | MonthAlt | Result Expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04564494 | 2019-12-22 | 2020-01-22 | 2019-12 | 2020-01 | 2 |
| 04564498 | 2019-12-22 | 2020-02-06 | 2019-12 | 2020-02 | 3 |
| 04512870 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01 | 2020-01 | 1 |
| 04566760 | 2020-01-07 | 2020-02-12 | 2020-01 | 2020-02 | 2 |
| 04500207 | 2020-02-29 | 2020-03-20 | 2020-02 | 2020-03 | 2 |
| 04502614 | 2020-03-19 | 2020-05-27 | 2020-03 | 2020-05 | 3 |
| 04503127 | 2020-03-31 | 2020-06-02 | 2020-03 | 2020-06 | 4 |

I tryed with:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF
```

but no with the result that I want.
Some help please.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff

Comment: I don't really get your expected result. How do you get that January 2020 is 2 months after December 2019? Or that January 2021 is 1 month after January 2020? Surely this is 1 month, and 12 months respectively?